# I can't connect Gitlab Pages to my Namecheap domain

Tags: gitlab, namecheap, gitlab-pages

I've had multiple problems connecting Gitlab pages to my domain registered at Namecheap. I've tried multiple DNS configurations and none of them seem to work. I got "Failed to verify domain ownership" at the verification step, and even when I got past that (somehow), I got "something went wrong while obtaining the TLS certificate". I've followed the instructions given to me by GitLab (below), what am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of Gitlab instructions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here, because I got in touch with Namecheap support. The example DNS entries provided by GitLab don't work on Namecheap (as of May 2022). The required DNS entries are

(Alias record) `Host`: `www`, `Target`: `<gitlab_user_or_organisation_name>.gitlab.io.`

(TXT Record) `Host`:`_gitlab-pages-verification-code.www`, `Target`:`gitlab-pages-verification-code=<your_code>`.

Note the differences to the Gitlab instructions. The Alias host is `www`, not `www.<yourapp>.<tld>`, and the verification host is `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.www`, not `_gitlab-pages-verification-code.<yourdomain>.<tld>`.

[image: Screenshot of Namecheap DNS configuration]

No CNAME record is required, in fact it conflicts with the ALIAS record anyway.